# Propositional Logic use of simplification?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can I use Simplification when it's not the only logical connective in a proof?
For example:

1. $(P \wedge Q) \Longrightarrow C$     premise
2. $P \Longrightarrow C$          Simp. 1
3. $ Q \Longrightarrow C$          Simp. 1

is this valid? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not a valid application of simplification.

We can only simplify from a proposition of the form $\;p \land q\;$ to $\,p$, and to $\,q$.

If the premise is $(P\land Q) \rightarrow C$, then you need for **both** $P$ AND $Q$ to hold in order for $C$ to hold. Separately, $P$ alone does not entail $C$, nor does $Q$ alone entail $C$.

Comment: ohh okay thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: For example, in the old Socratic maxim, (*featherless* and *bipedal*) implies *human*.  But featherless by itself is not sufficient, nor is bipedal by itself, to imply human.  [It is recorded that Socrates was mocked by the villagers who plucked a live chicken and turned it loose, saying it was human by this definition.]